# onGetErrorMessage for PropertyFieldCollectionData CustomCollectionFieldType.dropdown not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-custom-property-pane

I'm trying to validate the inputs of my PropertyFieldCollectionData using onGetErrorMessage.

It works fine for the text input (CustomCollectionFieldType.string) but for dropdown values (CustomCollectionFieldType.dropdown) nothing happens.

I could only find validation examples for the text input field online, so I'm not sure if the code is supposed to be different for each field type...

In the example below there's no actual validation yet, it's just to see if the code fires at all.

How can I get onGetErrorMessage to work for the dropdown menu?

```
   let mySelector: any = PropertyFieldCollectionData("selectorCollectionData", {
    key: "selectorCollectionData",
    label: "Configuration",
    panelHeader: "Configuration",
    manageBtnLabel: "Manage configuration",
    value: t.properties.filterCollectionData,
    fields: [
      {
        id: "value",
        title: "Value",
        type: CustomCollectionFieldType.string,
        required: true,                      
        onGetErrorMessage: (value: string, index: number, item: any) => {

        console.log(item); // logs to console on every update
          return '';
        }
        
      },
      {            
        id: "valueType",
        title: "Value type",
        type: CustomCollectionFieldType.dropdown,
        options: [
          {
            key: "A",
            text: "A"
          },
          {
            key: "B",
            text: "B"
          },
          {
            key: "C",
            text: "C"
          }
        ],
        onGetErrorMessage: (value: string, index: number, item: any) => {

          console.log(item); // does not fire when dropdown is changed
            return '';
          }
      }
    ],
    disabled: false
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no onGetErrorMessage function in [IPropertyPaneDropdownProps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/sp-property-pane/ipropertypanedropdownprops?view=sp-typescript-latest) interface.
[image]

Comment: But they are of type CustomCollectionFieldType right? Or are those implementations of the PropertyPane Props?(sorry if the semantics are off, I'm not an expert)

 https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/controls/PropertyFieldCollectionData/

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to the exact same issue and raised it as an issue on [PNP's GitHub](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/issues/321).

They agreed it was a bug and are including the fix in the next release. Hope this helps.